# AC through inductance only

Tags: ac, circuits

How will we have a current through a pure inductive coil connected with ac power supply? I am confused because the induced emf will be equal to the applied voltage but opposite in direction,

\$emf = -L\frac{di}{dt} = -vsin({\omega}t)\$

then how we will have a current through the inductor?

Comment: The back-emf in some sense exists because of the (change in the) forward current. You can't have one without the other.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Expand that a bit and make it an answer.  It's a pretty simple question, with a pretty simple answer.  The only thing that you could expand on is that lower inductances lead to higher currents, and if you want to get complicated, that the coil resistance influences things, too.

Comment: It's actually a superbly good question. And the answer is, I believe, far more subtle than it is likely to be given credit for. A good answer will probably involve Lenz's rule and will discuss superconductors (which will significantly change the answer.) I believe the OP is asking why it is that if the back-emf counters the applied emf, in order to counter a flux change, then why does the flux keep changing with the same applied voltage continually applied, with increasing current... A good answer will be a nuanced one.

Comment: I totally agree with @jonk here. The answer is tricky to unravel.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm still waiting to see an answer that deals with the hypothetical situation where the resistance of the coil is zero and the experimental results (Meissner effect, for example) involving superconductivity (answer isn't merely about invoking zero resistance; there's more to it.)

Comment: More significance to my question , if we connect an inductor with dc power supply the current at the beggining is zero because the induced emf is equal to the voltage of the battery at that instant ,but in the case of ac source connected to the inductor the emf at every instant is equal to the applied voltage ,then how will we have current?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of emf is artificial, it's created to have a single systematic formal representation to voltages which are caused by different physical reasons. We need it to have a solid circuit theory.

Inductive emf helps us to forget that physically induction induction happens in magnetic fields as well inside and outside of the conductor. Induction law states that if  magnetic field somewhere changes for any reason, then at the same place there exists an electric field which can be calculated by using the following equation (a 3D vector differential equation). If the change of the magnetic field happened to be caused by changing current in a conductor, the generated electric field is always directed to resist the change of the current. We model it with a voltage source which is thought to reside inside the conductor and we call it inductive emf. The well known equation for that emf has been known nearly 200 years.

But the inductively generated electric field is as well inside and outside the conductor. Otherwise we couldn't have for ex. transformers.

If we connect a coil to a voltage source, the voltage forces electrons in the conductor to move. The resistance isn't the only reason why the electrons do not get accelerated infinitely. If the current increases there's also the inductive emf which prevents infinite speeding. The equilibrium exists when the external voltage pushes electrons as strongly as the resistance and inductive emf together brake.

The equilibrium can be an evolving state (note: I call changing current a state because it's determined) if the external voltage isn't constant, but changes. Actually every voltage changes at least when it's switched on, nothing has existed from minus eternity.

Differently changing voltages cause differently evolving equilibrium states which can be calculated by applying the induction law, Ohm's law and Kirchoff's laws.. That's solving a differential equation. Sinusoidal AC voltage causes sinusoidal current, as we surely know and its peak value is calculated by dividing the peak voltage with the total impedance.

**Your case shortly:** Inductive emf do not prevent current because the inductive emf exists only if current changes. The current will evolve in such way that inductive emf compensates the external voltage or actually compensates what's left,  when the resistive voltage drop is subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to ignore the concept of 'AC' for the moment (which is always a bit woolly when people try to define it), and instead think about the *general* case where a voltage can vary over time, but always has some known value.

When we connect a voltage to a pure inductor, we know from \$V = L \frac{dI}{dt}\$ (*), which we can also write as \$ I = \int{V}dt \$ + C (don't forget the constant of integration!), that the current will increase, at a rate of V/L, which balances the applied voltage. So we have a current flow, that changes over time. Its absolute value depends on the history of the voltage since the start of time, which we usually handle by specifying an 'initial condition' for current at some reference time zero.

As the equations show, the change of current, and the applied voltage, always go hand in hand. There is no 'one causes the other', even though it sometimes seems that way to us as experimenters. If we apply a voltage to an inductor, then it seems like we've caused the change of current. On the other hand, if there's a current flowing in an inductor, and we open a switch, it seems like we've caused the high voltage that's subsequently generated by the rapid reduction in current ( ** ). So in this sense, 'back EMF' is a bit of a fiction, invented to allow humans to think causally ( *** ). There's voltage, and there's current, and that's all there is to it.

If we want to create a *special case*, and define the way the current varies to be cos(wt), then we can call it AC, and as its differential is w.sin(wt), we can use that to define the voltage. Then we can come up with expressions for impedance, and phasors, and the whole notation of AC circuits suddenly becomes available to us.

It's a simplification if we're happy with the definitions. It's an obfuscation if we're not. If you want to reason fundamentally starting from there, then you'd better be more careful than I've been with the signs and reference times in the definitions of what you mean by AC, which is why I advise against it.

(*) have I missed out a -ve sign here? I don't know, and frankly don't care. It depends on polarity definitions, or does it depend on whether I'm dealing with applied voltage or back EMF? If I need to do real calculations, then I consider what energy flows mean, and that enforces the correct sign.

(**) If there's any meaning to the sense of 'cause', like a swung hammer causes a cup to break, then it's always got to be one way. The cup breaking can't sometimes cause the hammer to swing at other times. So if applied voltage can cause current change sometimes, and abrupt current change can cause a large voltage at other times, is one really causing the other? No, they both exist at the same time, in a very precise relation, as spelled out by the integral or differential equations.

I labour this point, as it's often getting stuck in a 'voltage causes changes in current' mindset that gives people problems with intuitive understanding of inductors and transformers. An alternative is each causes the other, which makes ones head spin. FWIW, I find the best for me is that I change the experimental conditions, and the voltage and current change together. YMMV.

(***) It makes a bit more sense when it's used to help calculate what happens in an inductor with internal resistance, it allows the voltage to be split between the inductive and the resistive part.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused because the induced emf will be equal to the applied voltage but opposite in direction,

Your equation, \$emf = -L\frac{di}{dt} = -vsin({\omega}t)\$, has an error. You can't have a *sine* appear out of nowhere on the right hand side when there is no sine or cosine on the left.

If we start with $$ v = -L\frac{di}{dt} $$ we can look at what happens when a sinusoidal voltage is applied. Integrating we get $$ I = - \frac {1}{L} \int v\ dt + c $$.

Now if we apply a sinusoidal voltage we have $$ I = - \frac {1}{L}  \int v\ sin(\omega t)\ dt + c =  \frac {1}{\omega L} cos(\omega t) + C $$

The important thing to notice here is that **there is a phase-shift**. The voltage is sine and the current is a cosine and will lag the voltage by 90°.

Now note that the current that flows will

1. Decrease with increasing frequency.
2. Decrease with increasing inductance.
3. Will never be zero (RMS) for a sinusoidal voltage or current (although it may get infinitesimally small).

---

From the comments:

> ... If we connect an inductor with DC power supply the current at the beginning is zero because the induced EMF is equal to the voltage of the battery at that instant, but in the case of AC source connected to the inductor the EMF at every instant is equal to the applied voltage, then how will we have current?

No. There is no induced or back EMF unless there is a **change** in current. That's what the \$ \frac {di}{dt} \$ term is telling you.

Comment: More significance to my question , if we connect an inductor with dc power supply the current at the beggining is zero because the induced emf is equal to the voltage of the battery at that instant ,but in the case of ac source connected to the inductor ,the emf at every instant is equal to the applied voltage ,then how will we have current?

Comment: See the update.